# Strtok and tokenizing by tab, newline, space and , in C leads to seg fault

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, strtok

So the thing is I'm not sure why when I use strtok on standard input from a file, I can't touch the data. I can print out the token with 'puts' but I can't print out with a printf, UNLESS I have a newline in front of and behind it. Here is my code.

I originally found out when the code reached the chooseOp function, where I try to uses strcasecmp, and it seg faults.

```
while( fgets ( line, sizeof line, stdin) != NULL){
//Get the instruction from stdin
    token = strtok(line, "\t , \n"); // first token, should be a command
    //puts(line);
    //puts(token);
    chooseOp(head, token);
    regindex = 0;
    token = strtok(NULL, " ,\n \t");
    while( token != NULL){
        puts(token);
        if(token[0] != '='){ //If not the arrows than do whatever you want
            createReg(head, token, regindex);
            regindex++;
        }
        else{
            regindex = 2; //If arrows, then point to next in line
        }
        token = strtok(NULL, " ,\n\t");
    }
 ...
}

void chooseOp(Instruction head, char* token){
//Simple function to find the opcode responsible for this instruction
if(strcasecmp("nop", token) == 0){
    head->opcode= NOP;
    head->ismem=1;
    head->latency = 1;
}
...

}
```

Comment: have you checked if `token` is non-null before calling `chooseOp()`.

Comment: I can print it out using puts(token) just fine. So I don't think so. After testing it out, it's not null. I think it may be reading from the file weird.

Comment: There isn't enough code here to reproduce the problem, so you need to study how to produce a MCTRE [How to create a Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) or 
SSCCE ([Short, Self-Contained, Correct Example](http://sscce.org/)). It sounds very like your pointers are out of control, but it is not clear which ones.  The "only works with newlines before and after" sounds like you might have returned a pointer to a local array somewhere — or something else has gone astray.  If you've got [`valgrind`](http://valgrind.org/), use it.